# ng-Template CSS not working

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS ngDialog.
Expecting that the CSS in the document is applied to the ngDialog, but it hwas not applied.[image]

Code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="attach_account_template">
  <div id="attach_account_div" ng-controller="Opportunity_Controller" style="width:250px">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="account_name" style="width:200px;height:35px" />
    <input id="btn_account" type="button" style="margin-left:10px;height:35px;width:50px" value="GO" />
  </div>
</script>


$scope.attach_account = function () {
    //attach_account_template
    ngDialog.open({ template: 'attach_account_template', scope: $scope });
};
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: Are you sure your attach_account function is being run?

Comment: The popup is displayed. It proved the function is called. Funcion is called from an <li> on click. <a href="#" class="cbp-tm-icon-archive" ng-click="attach_account()">Attach Account</a>

Comment: working here..but not for me...http://jsfiddle.net/mb6o4yd1/341/

Comment: You don't have angular turned on that fiddle. It is throwing an error in the console that angular isn't defined.

Comment: Nevermind you do, in the external resources, but it is still throwing the exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113053/discussion-between-tmb-and-krishna-prasad-ambaripeta).